# Facebook link thumbnail doesn't show right image.

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, thumbnails

The site I have problem with is: 
http://www.blienikon.se/

The thing is that when I link to the page in facebook it doesn't show the right thumbnail(s) to choose from, even though I have the proper code for it, and it seems right on the facebook debugger page!

Thanks in advance!

/Wick

Answer (score 0):

The dubugger says :Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.blienikon.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bokatd.png' will be used instead.

Comment: The thing that worked for me is that I used both
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/url/to/image.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/url/to/image.png" />

and then did I do
www.blienikon.se/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
on facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
aka the site + ?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
after that it took a day and it worked!